# Unsupported element in Slideshow (Facebook Instant Articles)

Tags: facebook-instant-articles

I have an issue with Facebook Instant Articles validation. For one of my articles this error message pops up:

`Slideshow Contains Unsupported Elements: Only image elements can appear in a slideshow. Ensure that slideshow (at /html/body/article/figure[3]) only contains supported elements. Refer to Slideshows under Format Reference in Instant Articles documentation for more information.`

Here's the code:

```
<figure class="op-slideshow">
    <figure>
        <img src="https://www.example.com/image1.jpg">
        <figcaption>Caption1</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="https://www.example.com/image2.jpg">
        <figcaption>Caption2</figcaption>
    </figure>
</figure>
```

It was generated by the official PHP SDK, and in the example they are using very similar structure. (http://take.ms/nookv) Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. It had nothing to do with the structure. One of the images was a **GIF**, which as it turns out, isn't supported in a slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

you can't add a figcaption for each slide, only images can be enclosed within the inner  tags.
Correct format would be:

```
<figure class="op-slideshow">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://example.com/path/to/img1.jpg" />
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://example.com/path/to/img2.jpg" />
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://example.com/path/to/img3.jpg" />
  </figure>
  <figcaption>This slideshow is amazing.</figcaption>
</figure>
```